# dual of a weighted $L^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am looking at the weighted $L^2$ space $L^2_{\eta} (\mathbb{R}):=\{u: \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{\eta x^2}|u(x)|^2<\infty\}$, or in general, any positive weight function $w$ in place of $e^{\eta x^2}$, how do we identify its dual space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the dual space are just the bounded linear functionals on $L^2_\eta$. (:

What you are interested in are some nice spaces, which are isometric to $(L^2_\eta)^*$. And then, the answer is not unique.

First, this dual space is isomorphic to $L^2_\eta$, with the isometric isomorphism $J : L^2_\eta \to (L^2_\eta)^*$ defined via
$$J(u)(v) = \int u \, v \, e^{\eta \, x^2}.$$
(This is what you get from Riesz' theorem).

Another possibility is $L^2_{-\eta}$ with the isometric isomorphism $J : L^2_{-\eta} \to (L^2_\eta)^*$ defined via
$$J(u)(v) = \int u \, v.$$

Finally, since $L^2_\eta$ is a separable Hilbert space, its dual is isometric to $\ell^2$ by some not-so-nice isomorphism...

Comment: Perhaps it's worth adding that a weighted $L^2$-space is isometrically isomorphic to the standard $L^2$-space via $\iota(f)(x) = \sqrt{w(x)}\cdot f(x)$ (where $w$ is the positive weight function).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, this is a good point.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me, when i think about Riesz representation for Hilbert spaces, I usually think the dual are exactly the same object, however, I do not think the possibility of getting duals that are isomorphic but with quite different descriptions (functions in $L^2_{\eta}$ and $L^2_{-\eta}$ have quite different decay properties...)

Comment: sorry, this raises another question: suppose I want to consider the adjoint operator of the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$, defined on some dense subset of $L^2_{\eta}$ (say some weighted Sobolev space), I can use the identification of the dual of $L^2_{\eta}$ as $L^2_{-\eta}$, and the dual pairing should be given by $\int uv$, from integration by parts it is seen that the dual of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is $-\frac{d}{dx}$, in particular, the kernel contains the constant, since they belong to $L^2_{-\eta}$...

Comment: ...and when you use the first identification, see the dual of $L^2_{\eta}$ as itself, certainly, we cannot say the dual is $-\frac{d}{dx}$, since constants does not belong to $L^2_{\eta}$, so my question is how would you define the dual pairing using the first identification?

Comment: This sounds like a different question ;) But roughly, it should be something like $-e^{\pm\eta\,x^2} \, d/dx( e^{\mp\eta\,x^2} \, \cdot)$. It can be obtained by straightforward calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You may think of $\mu = e^{\eta x^2} dx$ as a measure defined on $\mathbb R$, then your space is just $L^2(\mathbb R, \mu)$, which is a Hilbert space. Thus the dual of this is space is itself. The same works for any nonnegative weight function $w$.

Comment: that's what I thought, too, but someone told me it's $L^2_{-\eta}$ which is the space with the weight function been changed to $e^{-\eta x^2}$, how could that be?

Comment: I can't see how the claim is true. @TTY